# awk not parsing the first line of file

Tags: awk

I am piping awk on to a set of file paths that I want to parse into comma separated output but for some reason the first line is getting ignored. I can't see what I am doing wrong.

File path example is in test file...

```
/home/user/folder1
/home/user/folder2
/home/user/folder3
/home/user/folder4
/home/user/folder5
```

awk command is...

```
awk ' BEGIN { FS="/" } { print $1,$2,$3,$4 } { OFS="," } ' test
```

But my output is this...

```
 home user folder1
,home,user,folder2
,home,user,folder3
,home,user,folder4
,home,user,folder5
```

It seems to ignore the first line...I have even tried if(NR>0) print but it didn't work either.

Comment: Why do you think it's ignoring the first line? It's right there in the output.

Comment: The first line is not comma separated so it is ignored in the sense that the awk command isn't being applied.

Answer (score 1):

I see what I did wrong. The OFS was being applied after the statement was executed.

Changed to...

```
awk ' BEGIN { FS="/"; OFS="," } { print $1,$2,$3,$4 } ' test


,home,user,folder1
,home,user,folder2
,home,user,folder3
,home,user,folder4
,home,user,folder5
```